# How to enable all disabled breakpoints in visual studio code

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, breakpoints

Does anyone know how to enable all the disabled breakpoints in visual studio code (v1.13). There is an option to disable breakpoints in one click. But I couldn't find any option to enable all the breakpoints. As of now I am enabling breakpoint one by one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the option to enable all the breakpoints by one click. I don't understand why this was not in the Debug menu.

It is in Debug window -> BREAKPOINTS -> right click to see this option. Refer picture.

[image] is

Answer (score 1):

You can try to install the [insiders version](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders).
[image]

Comment: Thanks Helio. I found the solution. Anyhow, I will try to use Insiders version to get latest features.